# Get product from a combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider the following table of Product

[image]

Say user need to key in a combination of **component** to get the **product**. If the user enter **ice** and **tea** the system will only display **iced tea** and not **iced milk tea** (or other possible products that has ice as their component). If the user entered only ice as the component, it will display only ice as product. If the user entered only Chocolate, no result are needed to be returned because the combination of the components does not adds up for a product and no other product exists with Chocolate as its only component

The product and combination of component is unique. No other product with same component will exist. Meaning ice, tea and milk will only produce iced milk tea.

I am a bit stuck up in coming a query (MSSQL) to get the result that I wanted. I can see the combination and flow but did not know the exact query to use.

Can anybody suggest/point out the right direction?

Thank you for your kind attention guys. :) :) :) xoxoxox

Added : 
table schema
[image]

Select * from Product
[image]

Comment: Please give us your table schema. What is the definition of the `Products`, `Component`, and `ComponentsInProduct` table?

Comment: Hi Dai, its actually in one table

Comment: How can it be in one table? Please give us your table schema. Is this denormalised?

Comment: Will you be executing your query in an application?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen why did you remove your answer? Thank you for your kind attention. You suggestion almost brings me to what I want and I am sure it will be useful to others :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, See my updated answer for a simpler approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *Relational Division with no Remainder (RDNR)* problem. See this [**article**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/) by Dwain Camps that provides many solution to this kind of problem.

You also need a string splitter to split your comma-delimited components variable. Here is the [**DelimitedSplit8K**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) function by Jeff Moden.

```
DECLARE @components VARCHAR(100) = 'ice,tea';
DECLARE @component TABLE(Component VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO @component
    SELECT Item
    FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@components, ',')


SELECT
    t.Product
FROM(
    SELECT Product, CNT = COUNT(*)
    FROM Product
    GROUP BY Product
)t
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT CNT = COUNT(*) FROM @Component
)s
    ON s.CNT = t.CNT
INNER JOIN Product p 
    ON p.Product = t.Product
INNER JOIN @component c
    ON c.Component = p.Component
GROUP BY t.Product
HAVING COUNT(*) = MIN(s.CNT)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2861d/5/0)

---

@Tim Biegeleisen, here is a much simpler approach:

```
SELECT
    p.Product
FROM Product p
WHERE p.Component IN('Ice','Tea')
GROUP BY p.Product
HAVING
    COUNT(Component) = 2
    AND COUNT(Component) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Product WHERE Product = p.Product)
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/81fab3/1/0)

Comment: Thank you for the answer wewesthemance. Spot on with want I want.